# Exclude a .class file from compile dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to include two SDKs from a third party into my app. I get those from a maven repository. I created an extra module in my project. In the build.gradle file of this module I put this:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.abc:abcFirstSdk:0.0.1@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
        exclude module: "support-annotations"
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.abc:abcSecondSdk:0.0.1@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
        exclude module: "support-annotations"
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

When I build the project I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForLocalDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/abc/model/DataModel.class
```

So this DataModel.class file is in both SDKs. How can I exclude it from the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying `@aar` as a `qualifier`, it will bring in the AAR file directory.

Gradle dependencies are just maven dependencies, for instance: (GAV@Q - Group Artifact Id/Name - Version @ Qualifier).

By using `exclude module` you are trying to remove a single `module` but you are using it on a single AAR file and not the actual maven dependency itself.

Can you post the actual dependencies? If not, you can try removing the `@aar`.

Sources:

- http://kylelieber.com/2012/06/maven-versioning-strategy/
- http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#default-behavior

Comment: The two libraries abcFirstSdk and abcSecondSDK are libraries from the same third party company which I need to add to my project. There is no documentation on how to add both libraries to one project. I just guess that the company uses the file DataModel.class in both libraries and I get the conflict. Removing "@aar" does not solve the problem. Which depencies shall I post?